# parse.com set default ACL in CloudCode for all objects created by user

Tags: javascript, objective-c, parse-platform

In Parse's Obj-C SDK, there is the function:

```
    // Default Security for creating PFObjects
    PFACL *defaultACL = [PFACL ACL];
    [defaultACL setPublicReadAccess:YES];
    [PFACL setDefaultACL:defaultACL withAccessForCurrentUser:YES];
```

Which as I understand, makes all future objects created by the PFUser publicly readable, but only writable by the PFUser.

I can't seem to find an equivalent option in the JS/CloudCode SDK. I would like to be able to set this sort of option for a User so all PFObjects they create will follow a default ACL pattern unless overridden, instead of always setting ACLs one by one. Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't appear to be a way to do this with the current SDK. Here's an approach with which you could start to add that capability.

```
// add a basic accessor for default acl
Parse.Object.setDefaultACL = function(acl) { this._defaultAcl = acl.toJSON(); }
Parse.Object.getDefaultACL = function() { return this._defaultAcl; }

// override initialize (which is empty by default) to set the default acl
// when a new object is created
Parse.Object.prototype.initialize = function() {
  var aclHash = Parse.Object.getDefaultACL();
  if(aclHash) {
    var acl = new Parse.ACL(aclHash);
    this.setACL(acl);
  }
}
```

A notable difference from what (it appears) the iOS SDK has is automatically reflect the current user. In my code, the default ACL would have to be re-set if the current user changed.